# Starting a program in command prompt just opens up another command prompt window

Tags: command, prompt

Does anyone know why when I type the following command in my command prompt, instead of opening the intended program, it just opens up another command prompt window?  It's the same if I create a batch file with the command.

```
start "C:\Program Files\BrokerLink AutoPrint\BrokerLinkAutoPrint.exe"
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An extra pair of double quotes `""` should make this work as expected:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\BrokerLink AutoPrint\BrokerLinkAutoPrint.exe"
```

`START` regards the first quoted parameter as the window-title, unless it's the only parameter - and any switches up until the executable name are regarded as START switches.

Alternatively, you could just use:

```
call "C:\Program Files\BrokerLink AutoPrint\BrokerLinkAutoPrint.exe"
```